# why method DrowToBitmap() is low quality in c#

Tags: c#

I created a program to draw text, the picture on parent PictureBox works finely but the resulting picture is not fine quality when I print it.
Can anyone tell me how can I get a high-quality printing jpg image?
This is the save button code:

```
if (sv.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    pictureBox1.Controls.Add(textBox3);
    pictureBox1.Controls.Add(textBox1);             
    pictureBox1.Controls.Add(pictureBox2);
    pictureBox1.Controls.Add(pictureBox5);
    pictureBox1.Controls.Add(textBox2);
    pictureBox1.Controls.Add(label12);
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
    pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bm, new Rectangle(0,0, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height));
    file.Save(sv.FileName);
}
```

[Preview result picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pb7Ot.png)

Comment: a) define "not fine quality", and b) probably: you need more pixels.

Comment: Draw the information. Don't use controls.

Comment: excuse me Can you show me a better code than this one?

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert on this but you might try the following:

```
    using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap(width, height))
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
        {
            g.DrawString(...);
            g.DrawRectangle(...);
            g.FillRectangle(...);
        }

        b.Save(...);
    }
```